# What does the prefix PX stand for on a Bloomberg Terminal?

Tags: bloomberg, terminology

Regarding `PX_LAST`, `PX_VOLUME` etc...

What does the "PX" prefix stand for?

Answer (score 22):

`PX` is often used as an abbreviation for price in Bloomberg.

Fields prefixed with `PX` are generally static fields: the value is requested only once and is based on whatever information is available when you send that request. On the other hand, real time fields keep sending new data as it becomes evailable.

As an example: `PX_LAST` is the last price as of when you request it and won't change afterwards, whereas `LAST_PRICE` is a real time last price which will keep updating if you subscribe to those changes.

Other examples include `PX_BID` vs. `BID`, `PX_VOLUME` vs. `VOLUME` etc.

Comment: More looking for what the P and the S letters stand for . In PX_VOLUME PX cannot stand for price, as that would mean PRICE_VOLUME. It is just volume so not really sure.

Comment: There is no S letters there, so I'm not sure what you mean. PX_VOLUME means Price Trading Volume - usually the daily trading volume of trading for that particular instrument.

Comment: When I am querying reference data service, instead of subscribing to intraday, will ```PX_LAST``` be effectively same as ```LAST_PRICE```?

Comment: @Den yes it should be the same - obviously being a reference request you will get a snapshot of the price at the time of the request but it won't update afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

Px is a French abviation of price (prix) and often used in financial markets, before bloomberg ever existed.

Answer (score 1):

These are just Bloomberg mnemonic representations of data fields “Last Price”, “Volume” etc.

Comment: More looking for what the P and the S letters stand for .

Answer (score -2):

You probably won't be able to find a direct **one-to-one mapping** for what the individual `P` and `X` stands for, because the use of `PX` is to avoid the `PS` abbreviation, which appears like the more common "postscript" or similar words like "post", and this is by convention set at Bloomberg. Also, ***phonetically*** it makes more sense to use `PS` instead of `PX`, "coz" (pun intended) native speakers generally pronounce price more like "prize" than "prise" (note these are made-up words so may or may not correspond to the actual word).