# Px_volume in Bloomberg

Tags: equities

1. I would like to know What Px_volume data tells us which we extract from Bloomberg?
2. If I want Number of Shares traded of a particular stock then what term I'll use in Bloomberg?
3. When I match the Px_volume data of a particular stock with data which is there on Bombay Stock Exchange website then it is not matching?
   Please help.
   Thank you
   Regards
   Priya

Comment: Different exchanges can have different volumes - are you certain that the data in Bloomberg is from the Bombay exchange?

Comment: Also, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8087

Comment: What ticker and ec are you using ? In Bloomberg a two letter "exchange code" in combination with the ticker can specify the exchange (or group of exchanges) that is being referenced when requesting price and volume information. If you do not specify it a default will be applied.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable comments. @Stanley sir, I am not sure whether the data is from BSE. As I want the volume (shares traded) of the constituents of S&P BSE 500 index. I just use PX_volume for the tickers of these companies. Nbbo sir, can you please tell me the two letter code of BSE and how I'll write on Bloomberg, as I am new to Bloomberg. Thank you

Comment: According to this, Bombay stock exchange is IB https://stockmarketmba.com/globalstockexchanges.php

Comment: You can press F1F1 to reach the help desk. They respond immediately and should be able to help with a question like this.

Comment: Thank you @Nbbo sir. It means i should write PX_volumeIb.

Comment: Thank you @Nbbo sir. It works I write e.g 3M IB equity and extract PX-volume. This is 3M India LTD. I would like ask one thing when I am writting 3M IN Equit in Bloomberg, what is IN refers in this?

Comment: Probably IN is all exchanges in India (or all the ones that Bbg knows about) i.e. Bombay plus others. Accordingly the volume should be larger for 3M IN than Bombay alone.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to a Bloomberg Terminal, you find all the available fields related to a given security and their descriptions at the FLDS function.

Comment: This could be a helpful comment, but does not answer the question.